# Understanding OpenMP overhead

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to understand why the following example code runs slower if it is executed in parallel.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;
void f(vector<complex<double>> &a, vector<complex<double>> &b){

    const complex<double> I(0,1);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for(int j=0; j<a.size(); j++){
            a[j] = exp(1.0*j*I)*b[j];
        }

        //Doing some work with a

        #pragma omp for
        for(int j=0; j<a.size(); j++){
            a[j] = exp(1.0*j*I)*b[j];
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1.0);

    int N = 12; 
    vector<complex<double>> a(pow(2,N));
    vector<complex<double>> b(pow(2,N));

    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int j=0; j<100000;j++){

        //b holds new data on each iteration
        for(int j=0; j<b.size(); j++)
            b[j] = complex<double>(dis(gen), dis(gen));

        f(a,b);
    }
    double stop = omp_get_wtime();

    cout << stop-start << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For N=12, the sequential code runs roughly 15-20% faster than the parallel version (4 threads).
My implementation of OpenMP uses thread pools so I should only pay once if the thread team is created. Where is the additional overhead I don't see?

For N=14, the code behaves as expected, i.e. the parallel version is about 4 times faster than the sequential one.

**EDIT**
Some information about the system:

Intel Core i7-6820HQ @ 2.70GHz

16 GB RAM

Compiler: g++ 7.2.0

compiled with: `g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp -O3 -lgomp -fopenmp`

Turning on code optimisation helped for the case N=12. The parallel code is now slightly faster. For N=10 the "problem" persists. I have the feeling that this is the behavior I have to expect but I'm not absolutely sure about the reason behind it. Here are the results:

```
+------+-----------------+----------------+
|      | OpenMP disabled | OpenMP enabled |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
| N=10 | 6.966 s         | 13.222 s       |
|      | 6.801 s         | 13.131 s       |
|      | 6.835 s         | 13.111 s       |
|      | 6.764 s         | 13.502 s       |
| N=12 | 27.323 s        | 23.563 s       |
|      | 26.886 s        | 24.002 s       |
|      | 26.950 s        | 23.331 s       |
|      | 27.260 s        | 23.2636 s      |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please show the exact measurement results, compiler versions, options, and the system you execute it on.

Comment: Do you actually see all cores being used?  If so I suspect you're memory (cache) bound. Or the parallel workload is too small.